# Zappa Update Dev raised an AccessDeniedError

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa

I'm trying to update my flask application deployed on AWS lambda, it was working fine at first and then i add CORS library to Flask app and tried to update it on AWS lambda, But when i run `zappa update dev` it failed with following error,

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation: None
```

I have given all the permission to zappa user in IAM, but still i cannot update the flask app on lambda.

Any idea why ?

Thanks.